# window.TopFrame is null error

Tags: javascript, html, css, frames, frameset

I am using a frameset doctype on my page and also use js on that page..

I get the error window.TopFrame is null error...what does that mean?

Also any reference to how to refer parent/child modal windows correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
window.top
```

to refer to the top-most window frame, and

```
window.parent
```

to refer to the parent of the current window.